# How to access two elements of same index level but in different parent DIVs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the HTML structure:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="left-column">
    <div class="row">User 1:</div>
    <div class="row">User 2:</div>
    <div class="row">User 3:</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
    <div class="row">James</div>
    <div class="row">Jennifer</div>
    <div class="row">John</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using jQuery, I am trying to access text() from the above structure to print the output in the following format:

```
User 1:James
User 2:Jennifer
User 3:John
```

Tried with :odd & :even pseudo selectors in the parent elements but in vain. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @perjan55 does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to do this: (see output in console)

```js
var leftCol = document.getElementsByClassName("left-column")[0]
var rightCol = document.getElementsByClassName("right-column")[0]

var leftCells = leftCol.getElementsByClassName("row")
var rightCells = rightCol.getElementsByClassName("row")
for (var i = 0; i < leftCells.length; ++i) {
  console.log(leftCells[i].textContent, rightCells[i].textContent)
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="left-column">
    <div class="row">User 1:</div>
    <div class="row">User 2:</div>
    <div class="row">User 3:</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
    <div class="row">James</div>
    <div class="row">Jennifer</div>
    <div class="row">John</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var outputArr = [];
$( "#container" ).find( ".left-column row" ).each( function(){

   var thisValue = $( this ).html(); //value of the row in left column
   var index = $( this ).index(); // index of the row
   var otherRow = $( this ).parent().next().get( index ).html(); //value of the row in the right column by the same index

   console.log( thisValue + ":" + otherRow ); print the output on console
   outputArr.push( thisValue + ":" + otherRow );
} );

console.log( outputArr );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map for one column and use the index in the callback to get the text from the corresponding column

```js
var textArray = $('.left-column .row').map(function(index) {
  var rightText = $('.right-column .row:eq(' + index + ')').text();
  return $(this).text() + rightText;
});

console.log(textArray);

textArray.each(function() {
  $('body').append('<p>' + this + '</p>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="left-column">
    <div class="row">User 1:</div>
    <div class="row">User 2:</div>
    <div class="row">User 3:</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
    <div class="row">James</div>
    <div class="row">Jennifer</div>
    <div class="row">John</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/ztsh89v8/2/)

```js
var left = $('.left-column .row'),
  right = $('.right-column .row'),
  result = '';

for (var i = 0; i < left.length; i++) {
  result += $(left[i]).text() + $(right[i]).text() + '<br>';
}

$('#result').html(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="left-column">
    <div class="row">User 1:</div>
    <div class="row">User 2:</div>
    <div class="row">User 3:</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
    <div class="row">James</div>
    <div class="row">Jennifer</div>
    <div class="row">John</div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<strong>Result:</strong>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way (see console output):

```js
$('.left-column .row').each(function(i){
    var $value = $('.right-column .row').eq(i);
    console.log($(this).text() + $value.text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="left-column">
    <div class="row">User 1:</div>
    <div class="row">User 2:</div>
    <div class="row">User 3:</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
    <div class="row">James</div>
    <div class="row">Jennifer</div>
    <div class="row">John</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @YoYo Not sure what you mean.  Could you please clarify your comment?

Comment: i mean the output your code shows is not the one which user wants

Comment: @YoYo It is the correct format.  It's just that you have to have your javascript console open to see it.  I didn't output the result to the HTML DOM because it wasn't specified as required.  OP wanted the output printed.  I just printed it to console.

Answer (score 0):

In a different way:

```
var $left = $('.left-column').find('div');
var $right = $('.right-column').find('div');

var result = $left.map(function(index, el) {
  return $(el).text() + $right.eq(index).text();
});

console.log(result.toArray().join('\n'));

User 1:James
User 2:Jennifer
User 3:John
```